# Why is Jupyter not showing all the results as expected?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying the following:

---

```
In [] : 1
        2
        print(3)
        4
```

and getting the following:

---

```
        3
Out[] : 4
```

---

why not get:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter just shows the last result default. You can set it like this

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

After run this code, you can get all of the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter normally just shows the result from the last expression in the Output. In your case, that is `4`. Jupyter also shows everything that is printed to the console. In your case that is `3`.

Your `1` and `2` statements do nothing, so they are not shown anywhere. If you want to show the numbers 1-4 in the output, I would suggest you print each of them, and do not rely on the return value of Jupyter.

```py
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
print(4)
```

or even more concise:

```py
for i in range(1,5): # start at one, stop before 5
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python starts complying after the print command, in Jupyter 4 also compiles like 3 and you have got " 3 and 4 ", but if you run this code through the cmd console or Linux terminal, your output will be just 3, because the compiler didn't find the python command for 4.